# "Watchdog" vs. "watchman"

Tags: meaning-in-context, comparison

[Rowhani's 'path of moderation' also shows limits](http://news.yahoo.com/rowhanis-path-moderation-shows-limits-191518872.html):

> Rowhani's aides have said he proposed an accord in 2005 with then-French President Jacques Chirac to allow uranium enrichment in exchange for the highest level of monitoring by the U.N.'s nuclear ***watchdog*** agency. The deal did not gain support from other countries such as Britain and the U.S.

Why does the author of the above article prefer to use the word ***watchdog*** instead of ***watchman***? Is there any notable difference between the meaning of these two words in this context? Which one sounds more formal and correct in this context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Watchdog* is definitely the more appropriate word in this context.

A quick look in the dictionary reveals:

> **[watchdog](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/watchdog)** (n.)
>   1. a person or organization that works to stop people from doing illegal things in a particular area of business or society
>   2. a dog used for guarding a house or piece of property

but:

> **[watchman](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/watchman)** (n.)
>    1. a person employed to guard buildings or property
>    2. a man employed to patrol or guard the streets at night

I can understand, though, why a non-native might want further confirmation that *watchdog* is indeed the right word to use. It sounds like it could be offensive. Fact is, though, that the term *watchdog agency* is a very commonly used term when referring to regulatory agencies in areas such as energy and finance, and has been for [decades](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watchdog%20agency&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). As you can readily see from perusing [this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22watchdog%20agency%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en#q=%22watchdog%20agency%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:2005,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=OK-_UZr6AYaA9gSjwoG4BQ&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.eWU&fp=36bf6ca446d00854&biw=1417&bih=802), the term is hardly considered slang, and is used in many serious and scholarly works.

On the other hand, for most native speakers, the term *watchman* conjures up images of a lone security guard with a flashlight, not an oversight committee.

Comment: +1 A *watchdog*, it may be observed, is generally regarded as  fierce, vigilant, perceptive and loyal, while watchmen have traditionally been recruited from the least employable members of society.